# Difference in meaning between the given three sentences?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

1. She asked me to give her a call when I **was near** her college.
2. She asked me to give her a call when I was **a few minutes from** her college.
3. She asked me to give her a call when I **neared** her college.

Are all three of the above sentences grammatically correct?
Do they mean the same thing?

Comment: Is there something about these sentences that you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all three *mean* the same things essentially, and yes, they are all grammatically correct.  I put mean in italics because they don't literally mean the same thing.

The first sentence introduces a condition of position.

The second sentence introduces a condition of time.

The third sentence introduces a condition of action.

Answer (score 0):

In the first sentence, she wants to make a quick getaway before you arrive.

In the second, she wants to make a quick getaway before you arrive.

In the third, she wants to make a quick getaway before you arrive.